# How can I move the entrances and exits?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

I haven't played RCT in years, so I assume I am just forgetting something, and my googling skills are failing me - I placed a ride (a log flume, if it matters), and I want to move the entrance and exit, because, well, they are in places where I cannot get paths to/from them. My usual plan, because I can't find a better option, is to delete the ride and start over and pay more attention to placement.

Is there a easier way to adjust my entrances and exits?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work in a few steps for any ride:

- Left-click the ride.
- The ride's information panel should appear.  Navigate to the Construction icon (it looks like a crane toward the panel's right-hand side) and left-click it.
- The construction panel should appear.  At the very bottom of the panel, the options to edit the ride's entrance and exit should be visible.
- Select the entrance or exit button, and you should now be able to move them to a new location along the ride's boarding station by hovering on any cell adjacent to the boarding station.
- Left-click to finalize your selection.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Probably goes without saying, but remember that the ride needs to be closed before you can edit it.